# Cannot override virtual methods from parent class resulting on error "cannot allocate an object of abstract type"

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to override virtual methods from a parent on a child class but I'm getting error "cannot allocate an object of abstract type". This is my parent class:

```
class GameState
{
    public:
        virtual ~GameState(){};
        virtual void captar_eventos(Tile *tiles[], Objeto * objs, Tipo * tipos, bool * quit) = 0;
        virtual void logic(Tile *tiles[], Objeto * objs, Tipo * tipos, bool * quit) = 0;
        virtual void render(Tile *tiles[], Objeto *objs, Tipo *tipos, float interpolacion) = 0;
        void message(char *);
};
```

And this is my child class:

```
class Menu : public GameState
{
    private:

    public:
        Menu();
        ~Menu();
        void captar_eventos(Objeto * objs, Tipo * tipos, bool * quit);
        void logic(Objeto * objs, Tipo * tipos, bool * quit);
        void render(Objeto *objs, Tipo *tipos, float interpolacion);
};
Menu::Menu()
{
}
Menu::~Menu()
{
}
void Menu::captar_eventos(Objeto * objs, Tipo * tipos, bool * quit){

}
void Menu::logic(Objeto * objs, Tipo * tipos, bool * quit){

}
void Menu::render(Objeto *objs, Tipo *tipos, float interpolacion){
}
```

When I try to create a new variable class Menu:

```
currentState = new Menu();
```

I get error:

```
cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Menu'
because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Menu'
virtual void GameState::captar_eventos(Tile**, Objeto*, Tipo*, bool*)
virtual void GameState::logic(Tile**, Objeto*, Tipo*, bool*)
virtual void GameState::render(Tile**, Objeto*, Tipo*, float)
```

Why does it says they are abstract within Menu? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt to implement the virtual methods of `GameState` in `Menu` failed to include the right number of arguments. They are each missing the `Tile *tiles[]` argument.

This means `Menu` is implementing three different methods, none of which override the `GameState` virtual methods. Thus the compiler error.